# Understanding Haskell's RankNTypes

Tags: haskell, types

While working my way through GHC extensions, I came across [`RankNTypes` at the School of Haskell](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/PthariensFlame/guide-to-ghc-extensions/explicit-forall#rankntypes--rank2types--and-polymorphiccomponents), which had the following example:

```
main = print $ rankN (+1)

rankN :: (forall n. Num n => n -> n) -> (Int, Double)
rankN f = (f 1, f 1.0)
```

The article offered an alternative type for `rankN`:

```
rankN :: forall n. Num n => (n -> n) -> (Int, Double)
```

The explanation of the difference is that

> The latter signature requires a function from n to n for some Num n; the former signature requires a function from n to n for every Num n.

I can understand that the former type requires a signature to be what's in the parentheses or more general. I do not understand the explanation that the latter signature simply requires a function `n -> n` for "some `Num n`". Can someone elaborate and clarify? How do you "read" this former signature so that it sounds like what it means? Is the latter signature the same as simply `Num n => (n -> n) -> (Int, Double)` without the need for `forall`?

Comment: Think of the body of the function as:  `(f (1 :: Int), f (1.0 :: Double))`. You cannot use the latter type signature for this. In `Num n => n -> n -> (Int, Double)` you'd have that `n` must be both `Int` and `Double` *at the same time*. Using `(forall n . Num n => n -> n) -> (Int, Double)` you have that the function `f` can be applied to different types and thus it is well typed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the normal case (`forall n. Num n => (n -> n) -> (Int, Double)`), we choose an `n` *first* and then provide a function. So we could pass in a function of type `Int -> Int`, `Double -> Double`, `Rational -> Rational` and so on.

In the Rank 2 case (`(forall n. Num n => n -> n)  -> (Int, Double)`) we have to provide the function *before* we know `n`. This means that the function has to work for *any* `n`; none of the examples I listed for the previous example would work.

We need this for the example code given because the function `f` that's passed in is applied to two different types: an `Int` and a `Double`. So it has to work for both of them.

The first case is normal because that's how type variables work by default. If you don't have a `forall` at all, your type signature is equivalent to having it at the very beginning. (This is called prenex form.) So `Num n => (n -> n) -> (Int, Double)` is implicitly the same as `forall n. Num n => (n -> n) -> (Int, Double)`.

What's the type of a function that works for *any* `n`? It's exactly `forall n. Num n => n -> n`.

Comment: Thank you. In "Rank N", what does rank mean and what does the N refer to?

Comment: The `N` refers to how deeply you can nest `forall` inside functions (`->`). In this case, it's nested inside a single function, so it would be rank 2. Haskell used to *only* support Rank2 polymorphism but since it now supports arbitrary ranks, this is more of a historical note.

Answer (score 9):

> How do you "read" this former signature so that it sounds like what it means?

You can read

```
rankN :: (forall n. Num n => n -> n) -> (Int, Double)
```

as "rankN takes a parameter `f :: Num n => n -> n`" and returns `(Int, Double)`, where `f :: Num n => n -> n` can be read as "for any numeric type `n`, `f` can take an `n` and return an `n`".

The rank one definition

```
rank1 :: forall n. Num n => (n -> n) -> (Int, Double)
```

would then be read as "For any numeric type `n`, `rank1` takes an argument `f :: n -> n` and returns an `(Int, Double)`".

> Is the latter signature the same as simply `Num n => (n -> n) -> (Int, Double)` without the need for `forall`?

Yes, by default all `forall`s are implicitly placed at the outer-most position (resulting in a rank-1 type).

Comment: More than a half-decade late, but I want to tell you that this explanation is one of the best intuition-pumps for Rank2Types.

Answer (score 9):

In the `rankN` case `f` has to be a polymorphic function which is valid for all numeric types `n`.

In the `rank1` case `f` only has to be defined for a single numeric type.

Here is some code which illustrates this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

rankN :: (forall n. Num n => n -> n) -> (Int, Double)
rankN = undefined

rank1 :: forall n. Num n => (n -> n) -> (Int, Double)
rank1 = undefined

foo :: Int -> Int  -- monomorphic
foo n = n + 1

test1 = rank1 foo -- OK

test2 = rankN foo -- does not type check

test3 = rankN (+1) -- OK since (+1) is polymorphic
```

**Update**

In response to @helpwithhaskell's question in the comments...

Consider this function:

```
bar :: (forall n. Num n => n -> n) -> (Int, Double) -> (Int, Double)
bar f (i,d) = (f i, f d)
```

That is, we apply `f` to both an Int and a Double. Without using RankNTypes it won't type check:

```
-- doesn't work
bar' :: ??? -> (Int, Double) -> (Int, Double)
bar' f (i,d) = (f i, f d)
```

None of the following signatures work for ???:

```
Num n => (n -> n)
Int -> Int
Double -> Double
```

Comment: Why would one want the rankN case? What advantage does requiring the polymorphic parameter offer?