# Why can't a function take a type constrained only by a typeclass?

Tags: haskell, constraints, ghc, typeclass

I don't have quite the vocabulary for phrasing this question (and therefore for searching for answers, so apologies if the answer is easily available). Consider the following

```
class RunFoo m where
  runFoo :: m a -> a

class RunFooWrapper m where
  doRunFoo :: (RunFoo n) => n a -> m a

newtype RunFast a = RunFast a

newtype RunSlow a = RunSlow a

fooExample :: (RunFoo m) => m Bool
fooExample = undefined

fooWrapperExample :: (RunFooWrapper m) => m Bool
fooWrapperExample = doRunFoo fooExample
```

This does not compile: `Could not deduce (RunFoo n0) arising from a use of ‘doRunFoo’`.

It seems that the compiler (GHC 7.10) is insisting on a concrete instantiation of the `m` from `fooExample`, and is therefore refusing to continue. But in this case I can't see why the program is ill-typed - `fooExample` explicitly defines a `RunFoo m` and all `doRunFoo` requires is a `RunFoo x`. So why doesn't this work?

As a supplementary question, is there some kind of special extension (something to do with existential types perhaps) that would allow a program like this? Ideally I'd like to be able to say that doRunFoo takes anything defined existentially (?) as `RunFoo m => m` (rather than taking any concrete instantiation of `RunFoo`).

**Motivation**

I'd like to create composable functions that operate on some aspect of a type constrained by a typeclass - I can provide a concrete example of what I mean if necessary!

**Edit with more motivation and alternative implementation**

I was curious about the answer to this question in the general case, but I thought I'd add that in the context I ran across this issue what I really wanted is for a sort of constrained delegation between monads. So I wanted to write functions in a monad constrained only by a typeclass that invoked monads in another type class. The top level function could then be run in different contexts, performing the same logic but with the underlying implementation swapped out according to the wrapping monad. As there was a one-to-one correspondence between the wrapping and the implementation monad I was able to use type families to do this, so

```
class (RunFoo (RunFooM m)) => RunFooWrapper m where
  type RunFooM m :: * -> *
  doRunFoo :: RunFooM m a -> m a

instance RunFooWrapper RunFooWrapperSlow where 
  type RunFooM RunFooWrapperSlow = RunSlow
  doRunFoo :: [...]
```

This meant that the resolution of the `fooExample` `m` was determined by the class context of the wrapper monad, and seems to work fine, but it is a very narrow solution compared to that provided by haoformayor.

Comment: This is just the `show . read` problem. You need to pick a type `n` for `doRunFoo`.

Comment: How should the caller of `fooWrapperExample` specify which instance of `RunFoo` they want you to use in `fooExample`?

Comment: @ReidBarton Yes that will compile but it sadly won't help with the issue here because I specifically don't want to force an particular type.

Comment: @amalloy Good question - the simple answer in that in my use case for this it doesn't have to - the real point behind the structure I was attempting to capture is that RunFooWrapper will impose a type at some point (i.e. the implementation of doRunFoo will be free to force any concrete implementation it wants at the time eg (bool :: RunSlow Bool) <- x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### RankNTypes

```
{-# language RankNTypes #-}    

class RunFoo m where
  runFoo :: m a -> a

class RunFooWrapper m where
  doRunFoo :: (forall n. RunFoo n => n a) -> m a

fooExample :: RunFoo m => m Bool
fooExample = undefined

fooWrapperExample :: RunFooWrapper m => m Bool
fooWrapperExample = doRunFoo fooExample
```

The `(forall n. RunFoo n => n a) -> m a` is the key difference. It lets you pass in `fooExample`, which has the type `forall m. RunFoo m => m Bool` (the `forall` being implicitly added by the compiler) and so the `m` unifies with the `n` and everybody is happy. Though I cannot read minds, I believe this type reflects your true intent. You only wanted a `RunFoo` instance, nothing more, and having the `n` scoped to the first argument provides it.

The problem was that your given code is implicitly typed as `forall n. RunFoo n => n a -> m a`. That means you need to first *pick an `n` such that `RunFoo n`* and then come up with a value with type `n a` to pass in as the first argument. This simple act of moving the parentheses (increasing the rank of `n`) changes the meaning entirely.

For an example of someone who had the same problem, see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446759/understanding-haskells-rankntypes). For a better explanation of `RankNTypes` than I could provide, see [Oliver's blog post on it](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-18-rank-n-types.html).

Comment: Perfect, many thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I use RankNTypes in other places, but I'm only just getting the hang of the way the foralls scope the type variables. 

One small change is still necessary though I think - as it stands GHC complains with 'Couldn't match type `a` with Bool', but adding another forall seems to solve that, so `doRunFoo :: forall a. (forall n. RunFoo n => n a) -> m a` ?

Comment: @sybilsleaf, that means the same thing. GHC automatically puts in `forall a`.

Comment: @dfeuer That's what I thought, but I'm sure when I tried it I got that compilation error. However I've just tried again and it seems to be compiling fine now so not sure what was going on... So thanks!