# haskell: calling a function with different types of lists

Tags: list, haskell, polymorphism

I have a function:

```
sum f l1 l2 = (f l1) + (f l2)
```

How to correct this function to be working when called with different types of lists? eg:

`sum length [1,2] ['a','b']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Haskell's RankNTypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446759/understanding-haskells-rankntypes)

Comment: Turn on `RankNTypes` and add the following type signature: `sum :: Num b => (forall a. [a] -> b) -> [c] -> [d] -> b`. Now, `sum length [1,2] ['a','b']` returns `2`.

Comment: @Alec why 2? Shouldn't it be 4?

Comment: @AmiTavory You are calling `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()` instead of `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Apologies, yes.

Comment: @Alec Right you are. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May as well flesh out my comment in an answer. The usual signature one may be tempted to give is

```
sum :: Num b => ([a] -> b) -> [a] -> [a] -> b
sum f l1 l2 = f l1 + f l2
```

The problem here is that the two lists must have the same type, which must be the input type of the function. The solution is to tell GHC that the function actually has the more general type `forall a. [a] -> b`, which means that we can pick multiple possibly *different* `a` instantiations and they all produce the same `b`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

sum' :: Num b => (forall a. [a] -> b) -> [c] -> [d] -> b
sum' f l1 l2 = f l1 + f l2

main = print $ sum' length [1,2] ['a','b']
```

Comment: @figasso No problem. Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't work in general, for example if your function was `map succ`.

Comment: @Clinton would you care to elaborate what `succ` would have to be? I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: The enum succ, but it actually doesn't work in your case, I'll detail in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There's no general way to do this at the moment unfortunately. You could try like this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43873449) suggested as follows:

```
sum' :: Num b => (forall a. [a] -> b) -> [c] -> [d] -> b
sum' f l1 l2 = f l1 + f l2
```

And whilst this works with `length`, it doesn't really work with much else.

The issue is that the type signature in this answer `Num b => forall a. [a] -> b`. That means your function must work for all types of lists, and the only sensible function from `Num b => forall a. [a] -> b` is `length`. If you think there's another feel free to give me an example, but I suspect all the other examples are either variations of length or silly ones that return a constant.

And if `length` is the only sensible argument for `sum'`, then it's silly to define `sum'`, you might as well define `sumLength` like follows

```
sumLength :: Num b => [c] -> [d] -> b
sumLength l1 l2 = genericLength l1 + genericLength l2
```

Indeed, lets define the following:

```
g :: Enum a => [a] -> Int
g = (foldl' 0 (+)) . (map fromEnum)
```

This is a weird probably useless function, but it does something non-trivial. It converts all the values to their `Enum` `int` representation and sums them and spits out an Integer.

So `sum' g l1 l2` should work, but it doesn't. To get this to work, you'd have to define a new function:

```
sum'' :: Enum c, Enum d => (Enum a => forall a. [a]) -> [c] -> [d] -> Int
sum'' f l1 l2 = f l1 + f l2
```

And indeed, too use any function with different constraints, you'll have to define a new version of `sum`.

So really, no, there's no way to answer your question similarly.

I recognised this problem and created the package [polydata](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polydata-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Poly.html), which you can check out on hackage (needs some clearer documentation I admit).

It does allow you to make functions which accept polymorphic functions that you can apply to different types, like so:

```
g :: (c (a -> a'), c (b -> b')) => Poly c -> (a, b) -> (a' -> b')
g f (x,y) = (getPoly f x, getPoly f y)
```

Which is very similar to your example.

`c` in the above is a constraint, and looking at the type of `g` should help you understand what's happening.

Unfortunately, you can't just pass an ordinary function to `g`, you have to pass one wrapped in a `Poly`, which is non trivial as you don't get type inference for the `Poly` constraint (any ideas on how to make this nicer appreciated).

But if you've just got one or a few functions that need this polymorphic behaviour, I wouldn't bother with `Poly`. But for example, you're finding this issue coming up a lot (I found it came up a lot in unit testing, which is what inspired the creation of my package), then you might find [polydata](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polydata-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Poly.html) useful.

There's also [heterolist](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heterolist), which I created as an extension to polydata allows you to create lists of mixed types and say, map over them in a type safe way. You might find that useful.

Comment: Regular `length` works, because `b` is chosen by the caller, so we can very well choose it to be `Int`