# Haskell - Why are we using RankNTypes for single type outputs?

Tags: haskell

I tried this code:

```
printing = print $ rank2 (+1)
rank2 :: Num n => (n -> n) -> Double
rank2 f = f 1.0
```

It threw the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘n’
‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature
```

If I changed `Double` to `Int`, the error also changes from ‘Double’ to ‘Int’.

This error is only resolved if I use the `RankNTypes` GHC Language Extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
printing = print $ rank2 (+1)
rank2 :: (forall n. Num n => n -> n) -> Double
rank2 f = f 1.0
```

I have read the answers at:

[Understanding Haskell's RankNTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446759/understanding-haskells-rankntypes)

But I do not quite understand why this error would arise when I'm not using a tuple as the output, such as `forall n. Num n => (n -> n) -> (Int, Double)`, where the tuple is `(Int, Double)`.  If a tuple is the output, the function `f` may face a conflict in choosing between the types `Int` or `Double`.  But in this case, I'm using a single type output..

Is it due to the function `f` being rigidly polymorphic?  If so, wouldn't this mean that being polymorphic is quite meaningless?  The function can't adapt itself to a `Double` or `Int`..

Comment: "Is it due to the function f being rigidly polymorphic?" The word "rigid" in the error message means "user specified". As opposed to type variables generated by the compiler, which are called "wobbly".

Comment: The function `f` is not polymorphic! Your first `rank2` is polymorphic, but its argument is *not*. ...and I think this is the absolute core, key misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
rank1 :: Num n => (n -> n) -> Double
```

Is short for this:

```
rank1 :: forall n. Num n => (n -> n) -> Double
```

You can write an explicit `forall` at the top level of a type signature using `{-# Language ExplicitForAll #-}`. It’s also allowed with `RankNTypes`, of course, but this is a rank-1 type.

This is the type of a polymorphic function with the following parameters:

- A type `n`, supplied implicitly by type inference or explicitly with `{-# Language TypeApplications #-}`;
- An instance of `Num` for that type `n`, also supplied implicitly by the compiler; and
- A function (`f`) from `n` to `n`.

The caller of `rank1` specifies the argument values for each of these parameters.

Inside the definition of `rank1`, it may call `f`, but `f` only has a single monomorphic type, being `n -> n` for the particular type `n` that the caller of `rank1` specified.

For example, `rank1 @Int` (using `TypeApplications` syntax) has the type `(Int -> Int) -> Double`, so in this case we would have `f :: Int -> Int`. (More specifically, `rank1 @Int` has type `Num Int => (Int -> Int) -> Double`, but the constraint `Num Int` is filled immediately by the fact that there is an `instance Num Int`.)

Naturally, the `Int` result of `f` doesn’t match `Double` in this case. In general, therefore, `rank1` cannot assume anything about the type `n`, except that it is in the class `Num`. It promises to work “for all `n`”. As such, there’s no way to get a `Double` from an `n`, because an instance `Num t` doesn’t offer any conversions *from* the type `t`, only *to* `t` (with `fromInteger :: Integer -> t`).

Contrast this with the rank-2 type in your question:

```
rank2 :: (forall n. Num n => n -> n) -> Double
```

Here, the `forall` is nested within a function type `… -> Double`. So `rank2` is not polymorphic, and accepts only *one* parameter, which is a polymorphic function `f`.

That function `f` accepts three parameters: the type `n`, the instance of `Num` for `n`, and a value of type `n`. It returns a value of type `n`.

So within the definition of `rank2`, it may call `f`, and as the caller of `f`, `rank2` may choose any `n` that it wants, because the type of `f` promises that it works “for all `n`”. Therefore, `rank2` can choose `n` = `Double`, which is valid because there is an instance `Num Double`. The specialisation `f @Double :: Double -> Double` returns a `Double`, which can, of course, be returned from `rank2`.

Since `f` is polymorphic, `rank2` could call it multiple times with different arguments for `n`. That’s why you see examples using a tuple, like `(forall n. Num n => n -> n) -> (Int, Double)` (note the position of the `forall`). They’re demonstrating that you can call the functional parameter at multiple different types.

Comment: this is the clearest exposition of this issue I've ever seen! please answer even more often. :)

Answer (score 4):

So you want

```
rank1 :: Num n => (n -> n) -> Double
rank1 f = f 1.0
```

If this *did* typecheck, it would have to be possible to use it, for instance, like this:

```
bad :: Double
bad = rank1 (\n -> n + (sqrt (-1) :: Complex Double))
```

But that clearly can't work, because now you're adding an imaginary number to a real one and the result is supposed to be still a real `Double`.

With

```
rank2 :: (∀ n. Num n => n -> n) -> Double
rank2 f = f 1.0
```

you prevent this sort of usage, because the function you pass as the argument must be able to work for *arbitrary* number types, thus it's not possible for me to add a concrete `Complex Double` in the mix, only generic `Num` operations:

```
allright :: Double
allright = rank2 (\n -> n + abs (-1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying out variations of my code.  Is this considered Rank-1 polymorphism: `printing = print $ rank1 (+1)`, `rank1 :: Num n => (n -> n) -> Int`, `rank1 f = 1`?  Because it works.  I find it hard to understand why the `n` variable, which is already typeclassed as `Num n`, does not associate itself with the type `Int` in the output when I use `rank1 f = f 1`?  Using the terms from my reply to @DanielWagner, why do we need to consider the different actions taken by the caller and the callee in the first place?

Comment: Because the signature explicitly requires that inside the `rank1` function, `n` should _not_ be “associated” (I think you mean _unified_) with any particular type, but left polymorphic. The point of this is precisely that the caller can choose what type `n` should be, which is the whole point of having a polymorphic function. If it's not a requirement that the caller gets to pick the type, you can as well omit the `Num` constraint and simply use `rank0 :: (Int -> Int) -> Int`; `rank0 f = f 1`.

Answer (score 4):

This definition,

```
rank2 :: Num n => (n -> n) -> Double
rank2 f = f 1.0
```

Doesn't work because standard rank-1 polymorphism in Haskell says that the *caller* gets to choose what the type variables mean. It would be valid to call a function with that type with an argument `f` of type `Int -> Int`. This doesn't work with that definition because `f` needs to accept and return a `Double`.

When you make it higher-rank you resolve that by requiring `f` to be polymorphic over all `n`, rather than working on some type `n` that the caller chooses. Now it's possible to use `f` at the type `Double -> Double` in the body and get a result that type-checks.

This higher-rank type isn't completely useless in this case - you prevent the function being passed in from doing anything outside the `Num` type class. It can add, multiply, use literals, and a couple other things, but it can't divide or use trig functions, for instance.

Sometimes that kind of restriction on the capabilities of an input is really important, and so the higher-rank type provides value. [`runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html#v:runST) is an example of using a higher-rank type to prevent the input value from doing things that would break Haskell's evaluation model and result in buggy programs.

But I'm not sure you actually would care about that sort of thing in this case. It's probably easiest to just go with a rank-1 type that supports what you're doing more directly.

Comment: Thanks, however, the same error is thrown if I use `Int`.  `rank2 :: Num n => (n -> n) -> Int`, `rank2 f = f 1`, except that in the error, the `Double` becomes `Int`..

Comment: @maxloo Yes, and the same reason applies, just swapping `Int` for `Double` (or `Float` or whatever): the caller gets to choose `n`, and if they choose an `n` different from `Int` (like `Double` or `Float` -- let's say `Double` for the rest of this comment), then `rank2` attempts to use the return value of a `Double -> Double` as its own return value even though it claims to return an `Int`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, thanks, I realised I also do not fully understand what is meant by a caller?  In my code, which is the caller and which is the callee?  I believe both of these terms are from: https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/explicit-forall#rankntypes--rank2types--and-polymorphiccomponents

Comment: @maxloo You might like [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820603/why-can-a-num-act-like-a-fractional/42821578#42821578) with further details on one of the ways I think about polymorphism in Haskell. There I also use the term "caller", but hopefully in a more clear way -- it is in contrast to "implementer" rather than "callee". That is, the "implementer" is writing the code that has the given type, and the "caller" is using something that already exists and has the given type.

Comment: @DanielWagner, thanks, I've read your replies at "Why can a Num act like a Fractional", but I'm not sure if I've understood the terms correctly, partly because I'm trying to link a implementer to a callee.  For my code, can `rank2` be considered a caller?  Then its type signature will be the protocol, and we can consider `f` a callee, which the implementer will start with on the right side of the equals sign.

Comment: @maxloo No piece of code is a caller or an implementer -- those are always people writing code! When we are writing the code on the right hand side of the equals sign of `rank2 f = ...`, then we are the implementer of `rank2`, and possibly the caller of `f` if we like. I am okay with "its type signature will be the protocol", provided you're willing to be explicit about why it's okay to say "the protocol" instead of, say, "a protocol" -- there may be many protocols it makes sense to talk about it any given piece of code. But I'm okay with "`rank2`'s type signature is `rank2`'s protocol".

Comment: @maxloo Another piece of precision I encourage you to pick up in your writing and thinking: "implementer" on its own is meaningless. You must always say what it is that's being implemented. So "implementer of `rank2`" is ok, for example. Similarly for "caller" -- on its own, it's not sensible, it must be in relation to some piece of code or protocol. (Sometimes context makes it clear which piece of code! But less often than you might think. Maybe less often than *I* might think, too. Let me know if you find it tricky to work out which piece of code is meant at each place in the linked answer.)