# mapping over RankNTypes functions

Tags: haskell, rank-n-types

Using `rankN` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446759/understanding-haskells-rankntypes):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
rankN :: (forall n. Num n => n -> n) -> (Int, Double)
rankN f = (f 1, f 1.0)
```

Why can't do `map rankN [negate]`? Is there some way to make it possible?

I think I now (mostly) understand the RankNTypes, and see I can do both `rankN (+1)` and  `rankN negate`.

(And why does `map rankN [negate]` give a weird error `Couldn't match type ‘n’ with ‘Integer’`, when I don't think there are any `Integer`s involved?)

Also, I just checked `:t map rankN`. It gives the dreaded `Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘n -> n’ because type variable ‘n’ would escape its scope. This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by...`. I see how that error comes about in some cases, but don't really understand why it would apply here.

Thanks, and sorry if this is a dup. (But I couldn't find the answer amongst all the other RankNTypes questions.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that it does not work by default is because the type of map is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, but you cannot instantiate that `a` to a type involving `forall`, in this case `forall n. Num n => n -> n`. Such instantiation is called *impredicative*, which was not supported (reliably) by GHC for a long time.

Since GHC 9.2.1 there is a new reliable implementation of the [`ImpredicativeTypes`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/impredicative_types.html) extension, which does allow you to instantiate impredicatively:

```hs
GHCi, version 9.2.0.20210821: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> :set -XImpredicativeTypes
ghci> :t rankN
rankN :: (forall n. Num n => n -> n) -> (Int, Double)
ghci> :t map rankN 
map rankN :: [forall n. Num n => n -> n] -> [(Int, Double)]
ghci> :t map rankN [negate]
map rankN [negate] :: [(Int, Double)]
ghci> map rankN [negate]
[(-1,-1.0)]
```